# Physicsjs getTarget is undefined

Tags: physicsjs

I'm trying to make a custom behavior and I'm not very familiar with physicsjs.
According to [the docs in github](https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/wiki/Behaviors#creating-a-custom-behavior) I'm supposed to use `var bodies = this.getTargets();` to iterate through the bodies
, but I keep getting an `undefined is not a function` error.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8xum92m/1/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Personally I find box2d is better documnted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the physicsjs version was 0.5.2 in the jsFiddle. The method getTargets was only introduced in 0.6. Here's an updated version of the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/r8xum92m/3/

also make sure to use `.on()` instead of `.subscribe()` now.